# Is there a way to auto increment a number field in RxDB?

Tags: rxjs, jsonschema, rxdb

I've got a simple schema:

```js
export default {
  title: 'hash schema',
  version: 0,
  primaryKey: 'hash',
  type: 'object',
  keyCompression: true,
  properties: {
    uuid: { type: 'string' },
    id: { type: 'number' }
  }
}
```

I want to have a table with a string field `uuid` as a primary key and I want to map it to an unique number that is automatically increased.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: to be honest, you might need to generate `uuid` yourself. With auto increment for numbers, you will need to look at `orm` functions. check out the documentation.

Answer (score -2):

"automatically incrementing" doesn't sound very UUIDish to me. UUIDs are supposed to be random and unpredictable. You leave yourself vulnerable to [the German Tank Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem)

Nevertheless, you can indicate a string should be a UUID in JSON Schema by using `"format": "uuid"`. It is only available in implementations supporting specification version draft2019-09 or later.